# How to get Excel to graph multiple series where series are "mixed" in a table?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, microsoft-excel-2016

I've got a table that contains multiple data series - and they aren't uniformly distributed either.  Example below.  As you can see there are multiple series here: Income, Short-Term Capital Gain, and Long-Term Capital Gain.  They don't have the same number of entries (i.e., rows) and the dates at which they occur aren't at uniform intervals in the table.

I'd like to get, for this table, an Excel chart with 3 data series lines, where X axis is a timeline and Y axis is the $/share column.

There are three things I don't know how to do:

1. Display, given a single time series with non-uniform time intervals, a graph over a uniform timeline.  (E.g., if I have a series with monthly dates but some months are missing I don't know how to chart that with "gaps" for the missing months.)
2. Display multiple series from a table like this where the series are distinguished by a value in a column.
3. Whether Excel is the right tool for the job or if there's something else I should be using.

.

```
Type                      $/share   Payable date
------------------------- --------- --------------
Income                        0.5   9/24/2018
Income                        0.5   6/18/2018       
Short-Term Capital Gain      0.06   12/19/2017   
Long-Term Capital Gain       0.69   12/19/2017     
Income                       0.48   9/22/2017      
Short-Term Capital Gain      0.02   12/27/2016     
Long-Term Capital Gain       0.63   12/27/2016    
Income                       0.44   9/19/2016     
Income                       0.47   6/17/2016     
Income                        0.4   3/17/2016    
Income                       0.55   12/17/2015     
Short-Term Capital Gain      0.04   12/17/2015    
Long-Term Capital Gain       1.44   12/17/2015    
Income                       0.47   9/21/2015    
...
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Splitting data into multiple series' in Excel Graph](https://superuser.com/questions/300788/splitting-data-into-multiple-series-in-excel-graph) and [Excel Scatter Plat with Multiple Series from 1 Table.](https://superuser.com/questions/750353/excel-scatter-plot-with-multiple-series-from-1-table?rq=1)

Comment: @ForwardEd - correct! [Excel scatter plot with multiple series from 1 table](https://superuser.com/questions/750353/excel-scatter-plot-with-multiple-series-from-1-table?rq=1) is the answer!  Thank you for your excellent search-fu!

Answer (score 0):

Excel has X-Y-graphs, also called 'scatter plots'. 
Create such a plot from the first set of data, and then use 'Add Data' to add the next, etc. Should be no big deal (u less you have hundreds of them).